# Custom keyword robot framework selenium webdriver python "object has no attribute 'get_attribute' "

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, browser-automation

I am trying to write custom function using  robot framework existing Seleniumlibrary  in python to get link from element. But I am keep getting an issue in get_attribute.

> Error : 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Library imported

```
from selenium import webdriver
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def get_one_links(locator,attribute):
    lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    links = lib.find_elements(locator).get_attribute(attribute)
    return links
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are trying to call the method on a list, you can only call on a single element. See the example below. The "get_attribute" property doesn't exist for lists, but the "get_attribute" property does for single element. For example:

You need to do something like this in your code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def get_one_links(locator,attribute):
    lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
    links = lib.find_elements(locator)
    for link in links:
        return link.get_attribute('href')
        #return link if thats what you want
```

Comment: When driver is `driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Path\To\chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: But you are not calling existing robot framework Selenium library. I want to use existing library.

Comment: I haven't changed anything related to robot framework. The method `getAttribute()` is a method that is declared in WebElement interface, and native to selenium. You just need to apply the operation differently to get your results

Comment: items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")                                                   
 does not work in robot framework existing library.     driver is only available when webdriver.chrome declare. But in my case I am calling existing library. existing Library does not recognize driver.

Comment: I have updated my code. The earlier example was supposed to be an unrelated example on how it would work. Can you see the update now.

Comment: Code is working but does not do the proper job. I want to get a link from this function. I am not getting that. Instead of link , I got <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bbfcc9a5d9c8e6a5c5427e32df78802a", element="15b5412f-6cc1-4b57-a0de-20eed1284dde"

Comment: What are you passing as the attribute value? To get just the link it needs to be like this `get_attribute('href')`, where this will get the link that you want

Comment: Yes, I did that. def get_one_links(locator): lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary') links = lib.find_elements(locator) for link in links: link.get_attribute('href') return link

Comment: Not return `link` you need to return `link.get_attribute('href')`. The former just returns what you posted above whereas the latter will return the link.